how to get back error form laravel to inertiajs/vue3 application?
Here I'm using Laravel 11 with vue3 replaced for blade.
so i'm using vue3 inside of Laravel framework with the help of inertiaJs
controller
 public function addInfo(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:25',
            'message' => 'required|string',
            'days' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        ]);
        
        $count= Information::all()->count();
        if($count >= 5){
          
            $error = ([
             'message'=> 'intonation not allowed more then 5 please delete old one',
             'status' => false,
            ]);


            return response()->json($error); 
        }

        $new_info = new Information();
        $new_info->title    = $request->title;
        $new_info->content  = $request->message;
        $new_info->days     = $request->days;
        
        $new_info->links    = json_encode($request->links);
        $new_info->save();
    }

VUE3
const form = useForm({
   title: '',
   message: '',
   days: '',
   links:[],

});

 form.post(route('info.add'), {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () =>{ 
        
          form.reset();
            lastInput.forEach(lastInput => {
              lastInput.remove();
            });
            console.log(error);
          showAlert('success', 'Info added Successfully');
          
        },
        onError: () => {
        
    }
      });

i want to know that how can i get  return response()->json($error);  to show in vue onError: () or any other process to show the error im using  laravel web route


Have you tried to return with error on your laravel controller ? for example:
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($error)

Then your error should be received inside onError, like this:
onError: (errors) => {
   alert(errors.message)
}


I use the following in the form request, which passes it on in the response for Inertia, you can access what fields failed validation.
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        \Log::info($validator->errors());
        
        session()->flash('failure', 'Correct errors shown below to continue');
        throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }

I also log any validation failures, for convenience.
